# nc command not found on SuSE

Tags: software-installation, suse, sles, netcat

I'm trying to use the `nc` command on SuSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11. I executed this line:

```
nc ­-4ul 192.0.2.2 50000
```

But I got this.-

```
bash: nc: command not found
```

This is the first time that I have the problem. I have used the command for other tests without difficulty.

I'll appreciate any help to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you don't have `netcat-openbsd` installed in your machine. Try:

```
zypper search netcat-openbsd
```

Then:

```
sudo zypper install netcat-openbsd
```

Maybe your package name will be different, so change it to what ever `zypper search` command return. This will install `netcat` version implemented by OpenBSD.

**Note**

- [zypper](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_usage_11.3)
- [nc-openbsd](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=desktop&version=11&service_pack=sp2&architecture=i386&package_name=netcat-openbsd)
- [netcat implemention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations)

Comment: I got this.- [link](http://postimg.org/image/rzmxm4we7/). When I try to install the `netcat`, it tell me that the highest available version is already installed.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to install `netcat-openbsd`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netcat` instead. It's installed by default, at least on SUSE 11.
Be warned that some options maybe missing though (ej. `-4`)